# FIeld hidden by FLS no longer returns records when search terms match?

Tags: search, field-level-security, fls

When FLS hides a field from a user, the search results would still return the record if the search term matched.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DcyUQAS

This no longer seems to be the case, can anyone else confirm? I tried a custom phone field visible only to Admins and while the records return on Search for me, it doesn't for a user where this field is hidden via FLS.

Comment: Not in a position to test right now, but I wouldn't be surprised as it's a bit of a security hole. You could work out somebody's phone number that you didn't have access to through brute force guess-work.

Comment: I haven't tested, but this would contradict the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_layoutoverview.htm&type=5), which states:
_Field-level security doesn’t prevent searching on the values in a field. When search terms match on field values protected by field-level security, the associated records are returned in the search results without the protected fields and their values._

Comment: I agree its a bit of a security hole but its in the documentation as linked, which is what threw me off

Answer (score 0):

This was a [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RXOEQA4&_ga=2.128787660.154025231.1649323953-281472891.1649323953) that was **fixed in 2019**.

After the fix, Global Search will no longer return matched records that are hidden by Field Level Security (FLS)